# Trying to avoid circular imports

Tags: django, django-models

Recently I splitted an app into two separate ones because I had 15+ models in it. I had got the "circular import error". To solve this I tried writing this:

```
from django.db import models

class App1Model(models.Model):
    app2model = models.ForeignKey(app2.App2Model)
```

The error I'm getting is: "NameError: name 'app2' is not defined". But app2 is correctly added into installed apps and into the path.

```
project
    -app1
        --models.py
    -app2
        --models-py
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ForeignKey` can take a string as an argument, i.e. `models.ForeignKey('app2.App2Model')`. Of course, you should try to design your code to avoid any circular dependencies in the first place.

Comment: but what happens if you need the model somehwere in your code. I have enough functions that need a function of one model or another?

Comment: @HansdeJong Don't make circular relations. Use `get_model` or function-level imports if you really need to.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Cat Plus Plus about designing code to avoid circular dependencies, but should you not be able to:

```
try:
    import app.model
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You should still need an import statement

```
import app2.App2Model
```

But if app2 imports app1 you would get an error like you mentioned.